# AJAX Call sends null parameter to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to send data from my razor view to controller using AJAX call ( without refreshing page ) by clicking the button. However my controller receives null .. appreciate your helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var fno = $('#FltNo1').val();
        var tagno = $('#BagTagNo1').val();
        var comment = $('#BagComment1').val();
        var dolleyreg = $('#Dolley1').val();
        //var fdate = $('#FlightDate1').val();


        $("#fastscanbtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("ScanBag", "IFC")",
                type: "POST",
                data: { fltno: fno, bagtagno: tagno, bagcomment: comment, dollyno: dolleyreg},
                success: function (result) {

                },
                error: function (errormessage) {

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

My Method :

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ScanBag(string fltno, string bagtagno, string bagcomment, string dollyno)
        {
```

Comment: hard to tell, obviously you send the correct js-object in data property, you should check the network tab of your browser dev-tools to see what values are actually submitted

Comment: you should add a class and then bind that model in ScanBag(Model m), than you can have the properties m.fltno etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems `fastscanbtn` is the id of a submit button, and you want to prevent the default behavior then do a ajax request, if so, you should pass a parameter e(as  Event interface) to the click function, then do `preventDefault()` function. You can try like below:

```
$("#fastscanbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ScanBag", "IFC")",
        type: "POST",
        data: { fltno: fno, bagtagno: tagno, bagcomment: comment, dollyno: dolleyreg},
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {

        }
    });
    
});
```